# Laravel - Access denied

Tags: mysql, windows, laravel, iis, server

I migrated my PHP website from linux server to Windows server on IIS. Now i am getting this error

```
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES)`
```

I am using MYSQL WORKBENCH 8 for mysql.

I cleared config

```
php artisan config:clear
```

I restarted IIS server

I create one other simple php file and tried the same credentials, i can connect to DB and can display result.

Here is my .env file code

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydbname
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypwdhere
```

Comment: Have you tried logging into the MySQL server with these credentials directly?

Comment: Yes,also i created one php file outside laravel application and test connection. i can connect to DB with same credentials

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

1. Check your credentials.
2. Please restart the Laravel server (if you're using built in server then close it and again run it by `php artisan serve`)
3. Clear the cache like:

   ```
   php artisan cache:clear

   php artisan route:clear

   php artisan view:clear
   ```

Comment: I tested my credentials my creating simple php file & connect to DB. I run cache clear commands as well. I restarted IIS server as well. what else can be the issue?

Comment: Are you using `php artisan serve` or any virtual hosting?

Comment: I am running directly from url, http://localhost/myapp/admin/login

Comment: I think it's about caching. If you already removed all cache you can restart the machine if you have access.

Comment: I restarted the server and IIS application as well. i run php artisan cache:clear in bash as well. but still the same

Comment: Is it possible your mysql uses `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I am posting here, which might help someone else.

I created new user for database other than `root` with host = `%`  and now it is working like a charm

Thank you all for your comments

Comment: What do you mean %?